# Ubuntu 14.04: Can't connect to new password protected wifi network

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager

After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 I can't connect to any *new* WPA2 wifi access points. Existing ones work.

Here is a pastebin of the syslog output: http://pastebin.com/QVgmRmXp

Here is an error that sometimes shows in a pop-up:

```
(nm-applet:28277): nm-applet-WARNING **: Connection activation failed: (1) Creating object for path '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/34' failed in libnm-glib.
```

There is a workaround, but it ain't pretty. When failing to connect, a file will be created here: `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<name of network>`
If I edit that file and add a password `psk=password` to the `[802-11-wireless-security]` section, then I can connect.

more info: http://pastebin.com/sLrq2s6M

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: `ps ax | grep wpa` to check if `/sbin/wpa_supplicant` is running.

Answer (score 25):

Follow these steps for changing to new WiFi network

1. Click on WiFi Symbol which is beside the battery symbol.
2. Click on Edit Connection which is at the bottom of the drop down.
3. Select the network on which you want to connect, and then click edit button.
4. Click on WiFi-security tab over there and enter the pass word of that network, save and close.

Now if you connect to this, everything will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

Wireless drivers for ubuntu and linux are a little touchy when it comes to connecting to routers with certain settings, I am going to recommend the best settings to use.

I recommend that you change the encryption type in your router to WPA2 with AES (CCMP). Make sure not to select the WPA or WPA/WPA2 mixed mode, as that will again need TKIP which is discouraged.

Go into network manager and set your wireless settings to match the screenshots for best results.
[image: wireless settings1][image: wireless settings2]

Also do:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo modprobe -rfv iwldvm
sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi
sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

this will be reset when you reboot but if it helps which it does in many cases we can make it permanent by:

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv iwldvm
sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi
sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi
```

Reboot

Comment: This issue occurs with all password protected WPA* wifi access points, including ones that I do not control and it has nothing to do with DNS and IPv6 as far as I can tell, either, since it never connects.

Comment: You can install wicd then uninstall network manager and see if that fixes your issue but you must install wicd before removing network manger, I looked at the dmesg and it is pretty standard output, the things I suggested have been time tested. Wicd is better with encryption then network manager.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this issue as well recently. I have another answer.

I installed ubuntu 14.10 on a new machine, and then transplanted my home directory from my older machine which also runs 14.10. This seems to have dragged along the keyring from my old machine, specifically these files:

```
~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring
~/.local/share/keyrings/user.keystore
```

The solution for me was to rename these old keyring files, and let ubuntu create new ones.

```
cd ~/.local/share/keyrings
mv login.keyring login.keyringold
mv user.keystore user.keystoreold
```

I got the method to create a new keyring from this forum post: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/7259/lost-keyring-password/

Replace `~/.gnome2` in their file paths with `~/.local/share`.

Once the keyring was replaced, my network manager worked properly again.