# Can't connect to WiFi with "Connection activation failed" error after upgrade from 14.04 -> 15.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 15.04, network-manager

I recently upgraded from 14.04 to 14.10 to 15.04 in succession. I lost internet capabilities each time, thanks to my having to use a Realtek WiFi dongle.

I was able to resolve those issues both times, but I now have this whenever I try to connect to a network by clicking on the option under the Network Manager applet:

[image]

I can connect when manually adding the network, but clicking on an option in the applet gives me the above error message.

I've tried reinstalling `network-manager`, `network-manager-gnome`, and `wpasupplicant`, but that didn't help.

**EDIT**: Something of note, I get a popup whenever I get to the login screen after rebooting asking me to put in the network password.

This makes me think there's something messed up in something that's creating the configuration files for the network, since it isn't saving the password.

However, I don't know what that would be.

**EDIT 2:** Another thing of note, if I try to connect to a network I've never connected to before, it just closes the menu and nothing happens the first time. However, if I click after that, it brings up the error.

Comment: Did you simply reinstall or purge? I suspect a bad setting resides somewhere in /etc/NetworkManager. You might try sudo apt-get purge; reboot; sudo apt-get install.

Comment: @chili555 I downloaded the packages via `sudo apt-get -d --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome wpasupplicant`, then ran `sudo apt-get purge network-manager network-manager-gnome wpasupplicant` then `sudo apt-get install network-manager network-manager-gnome wpasupplicant`.

Comment: Please see: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=193839 "The fix for me was going into the /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf file and removing the dhcp=dhcpcd line. "

Comment: @chili555 There isn't any such line in my file. Tried adding it and `sudo service network-manager restart`-ing, no change.

Comment: kindly check my [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1409580/780501)
This solution worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

Simply try again to install/reinstall network-manager with all dependeces.
`sudo apt-get reinstall network-manager`
`sudo apt-get build-dep network-manager`

ł.o.

Comment: I'm getting `E: Invalid operation reinstall` from the first command on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
and more errors for the second:
```Reading package lists... Done``` , ```E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list```

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Solved by this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/523101) in a post regarding Ubuntu 14.04.

Problem seems to be in the password prompt/popup. Setting the password in the connection details skipped the password prompt and the connection just worked.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install -d --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome wpasupplicant
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get purge network-manager network-manager-gnome wpasupplicant
```

However, this last step removed from my system several packages related to graphic interface and my display manager. It effectively removed `cinammon` from my system.

Then I did:

```
sudo apt-get install --fix-missing network-manager network-manager-gnome wpasupplicant
```

And finally:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After rebooting my computer, I was able to connect to the WiFi network.

In the Edit Connections menu of the taskbar, I clicked on the network I wanted to connect to and I activated both IPv4 (DHCP) and IPv6 (DHCP only). Then I changed , under the `General` tab:

```
Connection priority for auto-activation
```

From 0 to 7.

Then I was able to login to this open network through the browser.

However, after this process, I ended up with Xfce, instead of the cinnamon desktop I had before. I don't like Xcfe at all, but the important thing is to be able to connect now.

This is my hardware and operating system:

```
scasas@dappcw148:~$ sudo lshw -C network
   *-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 78
   serial: 74:70:fd:32:e4:a2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-39-generic firmware=34.0.1 ip=172.20.2.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:129 memory:ef000000-ef001fff
 *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: enp0s31f6
   version: 21
   serial: 10:65:30:6a:51:3b
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.1-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:131 memory:ef200000-ef21ffff


scasas@dappcw148:~$ uname -a
Linux dappcw148 4.15.0-39-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 23 15:48:01 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: received an error from the 3rd command:
```...```, ```Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.29) ...```,
```E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager-pptp/network-manager-pptp_1.2.6-1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'```