# nmcli the WiFi network could not be found

Tags: network-manager, nmcli

I'm running a headless device that I want to connect to wifi(it's currently on ethernet), so I'm using `nmcli`. I scan for connections with the following:

```
sudo nmcli dev wifi rescan
sudo nmcli dev wifi list
```

and the WiFi network I want is at 95% strength. So, I connect with:

```
sudo nmcli dev wifi connect "SSID" password "wifipassword"
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error: Connection activation failed: (53) The Wi-Fi network could not be found.
```

and I've tried copying and pasting from `list` to ensure I did not mistype the SSID, and it still does not work. It works fine from other devices that use Ubuntu and network-manager, so I know it's not the router.

How can it not find the network when I connect, but find it just fine when scanning, and how do I fix this?

Comment: Are you still having problems with this?  What version of Ubuntu are you using?  What happens if you try connecting to a tether on your phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never found a fix for the issue, but I believe I found the problem. I was using a virtual interface made with

```
sudo iw dev wlan0 interface add ap0 type __ap
```

to host a WiFi network, but `ap0` and `wlan0` had the same MAC address. Due to a problem with the RPi3 drivers, I couldn't change the MAC address(I tried `macchanged -e ap0`), but if I figured out how to, I'm pretty sure the issue would have been resolved.

Comment: Hi I am facing the same issue, can you elaborate what is the problem ?

Answer (score 5):

this one fixed the issue for me - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/519620/407616 
add this

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` 
then run

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

then you can connect to the ssid by

```
sudo nmcli dev wifi connect "SSID" password "wifipassword"
```

Comment: This is what worked for me using a j5create ralink usb wifi connector - https://www.staples.com/J-5-Create-Wireless-11N-USB-Mini-Adapter/product_2495870.  `lsusb` shows this - `Bus 001 Device 005: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter`.

Comment: This worked for me using nokia n900 + postmarketos

Answer (score 0):

Try this without password

```
sudo nmcli dev wifi connect "SSID"
```

Comment: Hello. Do you mean to type that SSID or do you mean the actual SSID?

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to connect a rather old a/b/g WiFi client to a mixed WPA 2 + WPA 3 WiFi network, I stumbled upon this problem, too. I guessed that maybe NM was not able to figure out the right settings for such an environment, so I ran `nmcli connection edit <BSSID>` and then configured the following settings:

- set connection.metered no
- set 802-11-wireless.band bg
- set 802-11-wireless-security.key-mgmt wpa-psk

(Do not forget to save, before you exit)

Pretty sure the first setting can be ignored, however the connection is stable for several days now and even when I reboot the router or the device, the connection is being reestablished right away.

Comment: Hello. You answer implies this only works for a few days?

Comment: The connection is stable since I set it up. However, this was only a few days ago, so I got no long-time experience, yet. Feel free to edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I face this  issue  in the past and tried  lost  of tips. But this solution
worked  for me  on  my Ubuntu 20.04:

**Improve WiFi connection by disabling power management for the wireless card**

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Then restart the  computer

NB:
The Wi-Fi power-saving mode is a built-in mode that allows devices to save power by analyzing the data usage pattern with time and then making sure that the Wi-Fi doesn’t drain too much battery of the device in question. But there is a need to be cautious, too, since this can affect your browsing experience.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by just turn your system in sleep mode then again turn it on this solve my problem without restart

Comment: Please read your answer it is not making a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

I was unexpectedly getting this issue which was strange. I was adding a wifi network programmatically with python e.g

```
os.system("nmcli r wifi on")
os.system("nmcli dev wifi rescan")
os.system("nmcli d wifi connect myssid password mypass")
```

It was a race condition where I needed to put some wait time between each command. Works just fine now.  Hope this helps someone.