# Removed network-manager, reinstall offline with .deb files?

Tags: networking, apt, updates, network-manager, internet

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and all of a sudden my connection to the wifi stopped working.  My tablet in same room continued to connect.  I restarted and used different users on my account, and deleted my connection to the internet and re-authenticated several times.

When I would try to connect, and authenticate I would get an error:  "connection activation failed", though now i forget where.

I saw this:
[Can't connect to WiFi with "Connection activation failed" error after upgrade from 14.04 -> 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653264/cant-connect-to-wifi-with-connection-activation-failed-error-after-upgrade-fr)

and it was suggested that I reinstall network-manager but that didn't work out of box so I did the unthinkable and did

`sudo apt remove network-manager`

without thinking.  I try

`sudo apt-get install network-manager`

but obviously it can't connect to the internet and gives me this:

```
      Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
    Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 network-manager-gnome amd64 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.4
      Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
    Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 network-manager amd64 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.3
      Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
    E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager/network-manager_1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.3_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

    E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager-applet/network-manager-gnome_1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.4_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

    E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

so I downloaded the files at

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager/network-manager_1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.3_amd64.deb

http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager-applet/network-manager-gnome_1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.4_amd64.deb

And I don't know what to do with them or where to put them.

Note: I hadn't updated for a while (recovering from injury) and so maybe my network-manager was out of date.

It has been suggested to me that I boot from a LiveCD, but I wanted to ask if it was possible to just install the most current files.

Answer (score 0):

You can install .deb files offline by following command

```
sudo dpkg -i <path of .deb package/packages>
```

or You can put .deb files in one folder and install all .deb packages at once.

```
cd <location of folder where .deb files are> 
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```